# Scheduling a one-time task to run on Windows Server 2012R2 boot

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, scheduled-task

As part of a system build automation script (that I'm using to create AWS AMIs), I want the system to reboot and then run additional post-boot setup tasks - but only once (so that when the system is imaged and then the image used to start a new instance, it will not run the post-boot setup tasks again).

The way I started to implement this is that the initial setup script (written in Powershell) uses `Register-ScheduleJob -Trigger (New-JobTrigger -AtStartup) ... -Name PostBootSetup` to setup another Powershell script run immediately after boot. In the post-boot script, I have:

```
Get-JobTrigger -Name PostBootSetup | ?{$_.Enabled} | Disable-JobTrigger
```

But when it is run I get this error (I'm logging all output of the post-boot script to a file):

```
Powershell : A scheduled job definition with Name PostBootSetup could not be found.
```

Which is weird because that is the output from the job that is currently running. I've also added just plain calls to `Get-ScheduledJob` and `Get-JobTrigger -Name PostBootSetup` that should output the relevant records, but there is absolutely no output from these - even though if I run these commands on a Powershell console after the machine started, I get the expected output.

Is it possible that a job can't access its own scheduled job record while running? If so, is there a workaround? or am I missing something? If this is not a good method to go about doing a one-time post-boot job, what would you suggest?

As a further note, I'm not very comfortable in batch, so I'd appreciate solutions that use Powershell or .Net or something that is more expressive than batch.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem? I am running into a similar issue where I need to run a powershell script on boot, just once but I can't seem to find a way to make it work

Comment: Eventually I just used the standard `ScheduleJob` interface and once the `PostBootSetup` finishes successfully it creates a file in a known path. When it runs again, it checks that know path and if a file exists - it exits without doing anything. Not ideal, but that's how we've done it on UNIX a long time ago (before they invented advanced crons, and systemd timers)

Answer (score 3):

Use one of the RunOnce registry keys, they were designed for exactly this kind of task.
They run once, and then disappear.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

Make a new string value key where the name is whatever, and the data is the CLI EXE and switches to what you want run.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
PS C:\> new-itemproperty -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce -name "myInstall" -value '"c:\temp\borland\setup.exe" /this /that /other'
```

Comment: What credentials do these are run under? Am I correct to assume that the HKLM one is run after boot as LOCAL SYSTEM and that the HKCU on is run on first login using the discussing l specific user's credentials?

Comment: There are no credentials for the RunOnce key like there are for scheduled jobs. HKLM runs as system. HKCU would be the first user making an interactive login.

Comment: I've read about it a bit more, and `RunOnce` doesn't run on boot at all - it runs on first log in. The point of the exercise is to run on boot and not wait for a user to log in, specifically because I want to automate the setup to complete without an active user session. I've looked at `RunServicesOnce`, but it doesn't look like it is working on 2012R2.

Comment: My bad, long time since I've used these... Thought HKLM RunOnce ran without logon, unlike HKCU RunOnce. And I cannot get RunServices to work on 2012 R2 either. Consistency... something MS continues to have less of.